# ADC bipolar input higher than Vref

Tags: microcontroller, adc

I have a position sensor that generates -5 V to 5 V as output. The usual approach would be to use an op-amp to shift it to 0-5 V and use an ADC with a 5 V reference.

I found that the [AD7606B](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad7606b.pdf) can measure +/-5 V with a 2.5 V Vref. I thought an ADC couldn't measure voltages higher than Vref. Am I missing something? If I can connect the sensor directly to the ADC it will simplify my circuit.

Comment: Depends on internal construction. This one uses internal trickery to make it happen.

Comment: That's true for most low-cost ADCs. AD has figured out how to make 5MΩ high-precision (~1ppm matching) fairly low tempco resistors on an IC chip, among other things. Very impressive. Pricey though. $40+ in one-off.

Comment: So, can i connect my sensors (two of them) directly to ADC? Sensor maximum output current is about 2mA, voltage is in range, so it should work, right?